# Word hand-drawn boxes

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, drawing

I created a number of text boxes using the "hand-drawn" outline option such as in this screenshot:
[image: text box with hand-drawn looking borders]

Now I can't find the "hand-drawn" outline option anywhere. Existing text boxes still work fine, but I can't figure out how to create new such text boxes.

Can anyone point me to the right location in the menus? I'm not even sure what such outlines are called, so Googling hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. It is called a "Sketched" outline. For some reason, it doesn't always seem to appear in the Shape Outline menu.

[image: Snippet of Word menu showing "Sketched" outline option.]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do something similar:

[image: hand-drawn box with text in it]

with Insert → Shapes → Scribble:

[image: location of menu]

Comment: The problem with shapes, including scribbles, is that they don't automatically constrain text within their borders. I think the OP is specifically looking for a hand-drawn *text box*, rather than a hand-drawn shape.

Comment: @wrecclesham: I don’t understand. What difference in behavior between shapes and “real” text boxes are you referring to?

Comment: You can disregard my earlier point! Just done some experimenting and realized there's no distinction. The OP must have used the Freeform:scribble tool initially. The only time the limitations of this tool become apparent with text are with shapes like circles and triangles, where text doesn't fit the shape drawn but the overall rectangle instead. For a hand-drawn rectangle, text reflows properly. (For really nice text reflowing into non-rectangular shapes, Photoshop is amazing.)

Comment: No, I didn't use the scribble tool. There was an option for various hand-drawn-looking lines in a "lines" menu somewhere. I just can't find it anymore.